# Validation issue with Zoo Visitor Update, SafeCracker Registration / SafeCracker Update Forms in one template

Tags: safecracker, zoo-visitor, validation

I have one template that has three separate forms. None of these are nested. The first is on the "/your-account page" and the other two are in modals. On this account page a user can update their info (form 1), add a dog (form 2), or edit that dog (form 3). They each have unique ids and have a unique "return." <strike>Include_jquery and safecracker_head parameters are set to "no" in each form.</strike> I am using Stash to store the variables for the dog forms and no channel:entries loops are being used.

1. zoo_visitor:update_form  [channel = "zoo_visitor"] --- include_jquery="yes" safecracker_hea="yes"
2. safecracker (registration) [channel="dogs"] --- include_jquery="no" safecracker_head="yes"
3. safecracker (update) --- include_jquery="no" safecracker_head="yes"

Each of these forms works as intended and creates/updates when submitted. The issue I am having is with validation errors. When I intentionally leave an input blank etc, my errors do not appear inline. I get this one (non-inline) error "The form you submitted contained the following errors: **You must specify a valid entry to edit.**"

If I remove the "Update Dog" form then validation works on the "User Profile Update," but not on the "Add a Dog" form.

At this point I have tried so many different variations that I am just stumped. The template, as you can imagine, is quite long, but I can add it if needed.

Thanks for looking!

FYI: Running EE 2.5.5 and ZV 1.3.25

**Update:** It looks like the issue is with the parameter error_handling="inline" so if I turn that off, then everything works great. I still don't know why this is, but I might have to resort to using javascript validation. Here is a link to my template http://pastie.org/private/v6f4keocja5auqcozsvw

Comment: For the zoo visitor portion have you tried using {field_errors}{error}{/field_errors} instead of the individual error tags?

Comment: Yes I actually had that line commented out in my markup. I just tried it again, but the same error was thrown. You still leave "error_handling='inline'" for that right?

Comment: Yep, leave error_handling="inline". I'm sure you've done this, but have you tried it isolating the zv form? I mean commenting out both other forms, then adding them back 1 at a time to see specifically which combo conflicts or if it takes all 3.

Comment: I had, but I isolated them each again for good measure!  The one that misbehaves even when by itself is the Update a Dog form. When I have just the Update Profile, or Update Profile with Add a Dog, I do not get the error msg. I realized that inline error handling doesn't really work for the modals anyway, as with the refresh, you lose the modal! It would seem that I might have to resort to javascript to handle the validation. Here is the Update a Dog markup by itself. [Update a Dog Pastie](http://pastie.org/private/nim2m246nu0ggpaow9ny5q)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your form3 isn't getting entry id or url_title for the entry which need to be updated.

In the case you are getting issue by passing entry_id or url_title as parameter within the edit tag dynamically, just put hidden field for entry_id or url_title like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="entry_id" value="[ENTRY ID]" />
```

OR

```
<input type="hidden" name="url_title" value="[URL TITLE]" />
```

As you are using modal for update form so entry_id or url_title can be fetched and value can be updated with some JavaScript.